# A* infinitely recursing on reconstruction of path

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, a-star

everyone! I've been having an issue with my A* algorithm. It's able to make it to the end and solve the maze, but when reconstructing the path, it ends up infinitely going in a circle between a few points. I've been spending a few days on this, so it may just be a stupid error that I'm unable to see.

Explanation really quick: the grid is an 2D array sprawled over one dimension (Odin doesn't have nD arrays) that says whether or not a spot is blocked, Point is a struct of ints x and y, and the 0 values are just temporary so I can see the values themselves instead of some astronomically large number. The reconstruction of the path is happening in another function, and code for that can be shared if needed. I believe the issue to be somewhere in this, however.

Here's the grid I'm using (this one starts at 1 but the actual one starts at 0):

```
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
 ............###...............
1.S..........###...............
 ............###...............
 ...#########......#########...
2...#########......#########...
 ...#########......#########...
 ...###...###...###...###......
3...###...###...###...###......
 ...###...###...###...###......
 .........###...###...###...###
4.........###...###...###...###
 .........###...###...###...###
 ...###...###...###............
5...###...###...###............
 ...###...###...###............
 ...............###......###...
6...............###......###...
 ...............###......###...
 ###.........###......######...
7###.........###......######...
 ###.........###......######...
 ############...###.........###
8############...###.........###
 ############...###.........###
 ......###.........###...###...
9......###.........###...###...
 ......###.........###...###...
 ###.........###...###.........
1###.........###...###.........
0###.........###...###.........
 ......###...###.........###...
1......###.F.###.........###...
1......###...###.........###...
```

Here's my code (Odin):

```
astar :: proc(grid: []bool,
              sizex, sizey: int,
              start, end: Point) -> map[u64]Point {

    // Initialize the "point_score_priority" priority queue
    point_score_priority := Priority_Queue(Point, f64) {make([dynamic]Point),
                                                        make([dynamic]f64),
                                                        0};

    push(&point_score_priority, start, 0 - heuristic(start, end));

    came_from := make(map[u64]Point);

    costs := make(map[u64]f64);
    costs[hash_point(start)] = 0;

    // Loop until point_score_priority is exhausted or we've reached the end
    for {
        if (point_score_priority.size == 0) {
            break;
        }

        curr, curr_cost := pop(&point_score_priority);

        if (curr.x == end.x && curr.y == end.y) {
            return came_from;
        }

        for next in neighbors(curr, sizex, sizey) {

            // If not the beginning and not blocked, proceed with heuristic
            if (!grid[next.y * u32(sizex) + next.x]) {
                overall_cost := curr_cost - heuristic(curr, next);
                curr_g := costs[hash_point(curr)];

                previous_cost, ok := costs[hash_point(next)];
                previous_cost = ok ? previous_cost : 0;

                if (overall_cost <= previous_cost && !is_equal(came_from[hash_point(curr)], next) && !is_equal(curr, next)) {

                    // Make the bigger heuristic values smaller for priority
                    costs[hash_point(next)] = overall_cost;

                    came_from[hash_point(next)] = curr;
                    push(&point_score_priority, next, previous_cost - heuristic(next, end));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Here's the helper functions:

```
heuristic :: proc(curr, end: Point) -> f64 {
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(cast(f64)(curr.x > end.x ? curr.x - end.x : end.x - curr.x), 2) +
                     math.pow(cast(f64)(curr.y > end.y ? curr.y - end.y : end.y - curr.y), 2));
}

neighbors :: proc(p: Point,
                  sizex, sizey: int) -> [4]Point {

    return {Point{(p.x > 0 ? p.x - 1 : 0), p.y}, // Left (lower check)
            Point{p.x, (p.y > 0 ? p.y - 1 : 0)}, // Up   (lower check)
            Point{(p.x < cast(u32)sizex - 1 ? p.x + 1 : cast(u32)sizex - 1), p.y},  // Right (upper check)
            Point{p.x, (p.y < cast(u32)sizey - 1 ? p.y + 1 : cast(u32)sizey - 1)}}; // Down  (upper check)
}

is_equal :: proc(curr, next: Point) -> bool {
    return curr.x == next.x && curr.y == next.y;
}

// Created by Tetralux. Thanks, Tetra!
hash_point :: proc(p: Point) -> u64 {
    hi := u64(p.x);
    lo := u64(p.y);
    k := (hi << 32) | lo;
    return k;
}
```

Here's the output of it trying to recreate the path:

```
Printing point: Point{x = 3, y = 9}
Printing point: Point{x = 3, y = 8}
Printing point: Point{x = 4, y = 8}
Printing point: Point{x = 5, y = 8}
Printing point: Point{x = 5, y = 9}
Printing point: Point{x = 5, y = 10}
Printing point: Point{x = 6, y = 10}
Printing point: Point{x = 7, y = 10}
Printing point: Point{x = 7, y = 9}
Printing point: Point{x = 7, y = 8}
Printing point: Point{x = 7, y = 7}
Printing point: Point{x = 6, y = 7}
Printing point: Point{x = 6, y = 6}
Printing point: Point{x = 6, y = 5}
Printing point: Point{x = 6, y = 4}
Printing point: Point{x = 7, y = 4}
Printing point: Point{x = 8, y = 4}
Printing point: Point{x = 8, y = 3}
Printing point: Point{x = 8, y = 2}
Printing point: Point{x = 9, y = 2}
Printing point: Point{x = 9, y = 1}
Printing point: Point{x = 9, y = 0}
Printing point: Point{x = 8, y = 0}
Printing point: Point{x = 7, y = 0}
Printing point: Point{x = 6, y = 0}
Printing point: Point{x = 5, y = 0}
Printing point: Point{x = 5, y = 1}
Printing point: Point{x = 4, y = 1}
Printing point: Point{x = 4, y = 2}
Printing point: Point{x = 4, y = 3}
Printing point: Point{x = 4, y = 4}
Printing point: Point{x = 4, y = 5}
Printing point: Point{x = 3, y = 5}
Printing point: Point{x = 2, y = 5}
Printing point: Point{x = 2, y = 6}
Printing point: Point{x = 3, y = 6}
Printing point: Point{x = 3, y = 5}
Printing point: Point{x = 2, y = 5}
Printing point: Point{x = 2, y = 6}
Printing point: Point{x = 3, y = 6}
Printing point: Point{x = 3, y = 5}
Printing point: Point{x = 2, y = 5}
Printing point: Point{x = 2, y = 6}
Printing point: Point{x = 3, y = 6}
Printing point: Point{x = 3, y = 5}
Printing point: Point{x = 2, y = 5}
Printing point: Point{x = 2, y = 6}
Printing point: Point{x = 3, y = 6}
Printing point: Point{x = 3, y = 5}
...
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd like a straight answer, please, as I've been working on this for several days. What did I do wrong and what do I need to change to get it to work?

If needed, I can share a dump of each individual step the algorithm is taking, but it's quite large. Thank you guys so much.

Comment: As your heuristic function is "admissible", there is no reason to visit the same node twice and overwrite `came_from`. So if `came_from[hash_point(next)]` already had a value assigned to it (from a previous visit), you should ignore `next` and continue with the next neighbor. No need to get and compare `previous_cost`.

Comment: trincot, what do you mean by “admissible”? Is there a better way to do it? I assumed the heuristic function would be based on a straight line. Also, how would removing the comparison check be able to revisit a cell that it potentially reached through a higher heuristic value? How does that not block off cells and potentially the best path?

Comment: Look up 'admissible' in context of A*: it is a good thing, not criticism ;) You will never get the situation where you get a better score when revisiting a node.

Comment: I thought the cost was cumulative, depending on the total score of the path that it took to get there. Is this understanding wrong?

Comment: True. The priority queue ensures you visit a node first with the cheapest cost. So no need to consider a different path to it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I managed to figure it out thanks to trincot! I needed to check to see if the value was already in `came_from`. Here's my newest version:

```
astar :: proc(grid: []bool,
              sizex, sizey: int,
              start, end: Point) -> map[u64]Point {

    // Initialize the "point_score_priority" priority queue
    point_score_priority := Priority_Queue(Point, f64) {make([dynamic]Point),
                                            make([dynamic]f64),
                                            0};

    push(&point_score_priority, start, 0 - heuristic(start, end));

    came_from := make(map[u64]Point);

    costs := make(map[u64]f64);
    costs[hash_point(start)] = 0;

    // Loop until point_score_priority is exhausted or we've reached the end
    for {
        if (point_score_priority.size == 0) {
            break;
        }

        curr, curr_cost := pop(&point_score_priority);

        if (curr.x == end.x && curr.y == end.y) {
            return came_from;
        }

        for next in neighbors(curr, sizex, sizey) {
            // If not the beginning and not blocked, proceed with heuristic
            if (!grid[next.y * u32(sizex) + next.x]) {
                overall_cost := curr_cost - heuristic(curr, next);
                curr_g := costs[hash_point(curr)];
                previous_cost, ok := costs[hash_point(next)];
                previous_cost = ok ? previous_cost : 0;
                if (overall_cost <= previous_cost && !is_equal(came_from[hash_point(curr)], next) && !is_equal(curr, next)) {
                    // Make the bigger heuristic values smaller for priority
                    costs[hash_point(next)] = overall_cost;
                    if (!(hash_point(next) in came_from)) {
                        came_from[hash_point(next)] = curr;
                    }

                    push(&point_score_priority, next, previous_cost - heuristic(next, end));

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Note the new check :)
It works perfectly! Thank you, trincot :)

```
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
 ///.........###///////////////
1/S/.........###///////////////
 ///.........###///////////////
 ///#########//////#########///
2///#########//////#########///
 ///#########//////#########///
 ///###...###///###...###//////
3///###...###///###...###//////
 ///###...###///###...###//////
 ///......###///###...###///###
4///......###///###...###///###
 ///......###///###...###///###
 ///###...###///###...//////...
5///###...###///###...//////...
 ///###...###///###...//////...
 ///////////////###//////###...
6///////////////###//////###...
 ///////////////###//////###...
 ###.........###...///######...
7###.........###...///######...
 ###.........###...///######...
 ############...###//////...###
8############...###//////...###
 ############...###//////...###
 ......###/////////###///###...
9......###/////////###///###...
 ......###/////////###///###...
 ###......///###///###///......
1###......///###///###///......
0###......///###///###///......
 ......###///###/////////###...
1......###/F/###/////////###...
1......###///###/////////###...
```